# Blocking Links From Being Indexed in Opencart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, robots.txt

I seem to be receiving a lot of 404 errors from Google Webmaster tools of late. Is there a way to prohibit these sort of links from being indexed? and where do they come from?

Appreciate if you could shed some light on this matter. Thanks in advance.

I am on opencart 1.5.4.1.

These are the 404 errors

```
http://mydomain.com/product/search&filter_tag=Purse&sort=rating&order=ASC&limit=25
http://mydomain.com/product/search&sort=p.price&order=DESC&filter_tag=&limit=25
http://mydomain.com/cart?qty=1&id_product=323&token=bfcf19e76ed4a88abd8508e8dc097a70&add
```

I've also included the following entries in my robots.txt to no avail

```
User-agent: Googlebot

User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Disallow: /*?limit
Disallow: /*&limit
Disallow: /*?sort
Disallow: /*&sort
Disallow: /*?route=checkout
Disallow: /*?route=account
Disallow: /*?route=product/search
Disallow: /*?route=affiliate
Disallow: /*&keyword
Disallow: /*?page=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you are using an extension that is trying to rewrite ugly url's to better/more friendly ones - or were at one point. You should use .htaccess to rewrite the bad URL's to the correct ones rather than just blocking pages if you can. This will help your site

Comment: Thanks Jay. I was indeed using an extension to change it to SEF links previously but disabled after it caused some compatibility issues. As for the htaccess can you give me some pointers on how to redirect the bad urls? my errors keep stacking up.

Comment: There are plenty of guides online on how to do this (and on this site). Here's an example - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/seo-search-engine-friendly-redirects-without-mod_rewrite.html